# How to set console language to English in KDE?

Tags: kde, language-support, locale

I was experimenting with regional setting in KDE and it set UI language to Russian for me. Later I changed UI language back to English, but it still remained Russian in console.

How to change that?

Setting

```
LANGUAGE=en_US
```

to `.profile` didn't help.

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:ru
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How to fix?

---

```
(base) dimskraft@studebaker:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:ru
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
(base) dimskraft@studebaker:~$ cat /etc/default/locale
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `/etc/default/locale`. This command should do it:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then, after next reboot, the language should be English also in console.

Comment: No, it didn't work. Apparently, `KDE` sets locale somewhen later.

Comment: @Dims: It does indeed, but I didn't think it did so for the console. Can you please run the command `cat /etc/default/locale` and show us what it outputs?

Comment: I did this already :)

Comment: @Dims: Oops. You did. Then I'm lost, unfortunately.

Comment: May be use colon, not dot?

Comment: @Dims: Where would you do that?

Comment: I think OP needs to fix the `LANGUAGE` var (which is currently `en_US:ru`) rather than `LANG` which is `en_US.UTF-8` anyway

Comment: @ashvatthama: Good catch. The question is where that incorrect list is set. Probably in some KDE specific file in `$HOME`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson OP @Dims could use bash's trace feature: run `PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2` to simulate a login shell and find out where each env var came from. Taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from.

Answer (score 0):

If I put `export LANGUAGE=en_US` in my `.profile`, it does not work for me either. But setting `LANGUAGE` manually in the terminal, before executing other commands, worked. So I just added that line to my `.bashrc`, which did the job.